# django ListView with aggregated data from another model

Tags: django, join, django-models

I want to create a list of my projects with the summary of cost elements connected to each project. How can I do that in django view?
The head row of my expected table is:

```
Project name, Sum cost of activities
Proj1   100
Proj2   150
```

Here are my models:

```python
class Project(models.Model):
   name = CharField("Name",max_length=50)

class Activity(models.Model):
   cost = BigIntegerField("Cost", default=0)
   project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,)

class ProjectListView(ListView):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()  #model = Project

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ??? # want to calculate sum cost of activities somehow
        return data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate the `Project`s with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class ProjectListView(ListView):
    queryset = Project.objects.annotate(total_cost=Sum('activity__cost'))
```

The `Project`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.total_cost` that contains the sum of the `cost`s of the *related* `Activity`s, so in your template you can render these for example with:

```
{% for project in object_list %}
    {{ project.name }}: {{ project.total_cost }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT project.*
       SUM(activity.cost) AS total_cost
FROM project
LEFT OUTER JOIN activity ON activity.project_id = project.id
```

For `Project`s *without* related `Activity` objects, the sum will be `NULL` (so `None` at the Python/Django level). You can make use of an [**`Coalesce`** expression [Djang-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to use `0` instead:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class ProjectListView(ListView):
    queryset = Project.objects.annotate(
        total_cost=Coalesce(Sum('activity__cost'), Value(0))
    )
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you very much. Django is a great tool but - for me - its documentation is taciturn and lacks useful examples... Thanks again